# utm_content param not getting recorded in GA4 for email links

Tags: google-analytics-4, utm-tracking

The value of the umt_content query param is not getting recorded in GA4 for email links. When I put the dimension "first user manual ad content" in the filters then it shows me (not set) against the email links. How do I fix it? i have read a lot of blogs and articles but nothing seems to be working. Screenshot attached below.

[image]

I have reviewed the utm_content parameter and found no spelling errors. However, it seems to be functioning correctly for our Facebook links, but not for links sent through email.